# FIWARE: How to access to instance without "public instance"?

Tags: django, routes, fiware

two instances:

1.- Orion  with 192.168.x.1, public like 130.a.b.c
2.- Keystone with 192.168.x.2. Port 8000 opened and tested from localhost
3.- instances have the same routing rule group.

I edit my security group rules adding port 8000 with a cidr 192.168.x.2/32. Now i test it with telnet from my computer:

telnet 130.a.b.c 8000

result:   Connection time out.

i'm wrong? how can i connect to port 8000 from my computer to my second instance using the public Ip (configured in first instance) ? Or need a second public Ip?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this: IPForwarding with iptables, haproxy, etc.

However, I thinK that the easiest way to do this would be SSH Port forwarding in your host with the public IP:

```
ssh -f -N -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -L 0:8000:192.168.x.2:8000 $YOUR_USER@192.168.x.1:8000
```

- -L 0:8000:192.168.x.2:8000 means that It'll listen every network interface (0:8000) and will send every query to 192.168.x.2:8000
- If you don't have a password to your user or ssh is not configured to accept passwords, you could consider either adding a new authorized key (so you can locally login) or connecting your public IP using -A so your credentials can be forwarded:
  *

  ```
  ssh -A -i $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE $YOUR_USER@130.a.b.c
  ```

Comment: thanks @jicarretero, but it is not my aim. I'll trying to connect via browser to horizon published in the second instance in port 8000, using the public ip configured in first instance.